# permalink independent on the post's name stored in the database

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to make a custom permalink structure for my posts.

```
www.example.com / post / %post_id% / %posttitle% /
```

In this permalink, the post's ID comes first, then the post's title after it.

---

### Things I know until now

`postname` is usually stored in the `wp_posts` table in the `post_name` row, and it controlles the post's URL. ie: if the post's `post_name` is `my-post-name`, it's default URL will be `www.example.com/post/my-post-name`.

post names are stored in the database in a way such that every post has a unique post name. If two posts have the same title (for example `new-advanced-topic`), the first post's name will be `new-advanced-topic` and the second post's name will be `new-advanced-topic-2`. And so there URLs will differ from each other.

---

### What I want

But I don't want the post's URL to depend on the post's name stored in the database.

The structure I want is similar to

```
www.example.com / post / %post_id% / %posttitle% /
```

Suppose that There is 2 posts stored in the database with these values

```
╔════╦════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ID ║     post_title     ║      post_name      ║
╠════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 25 ║ new-advanced-topic ║ new-advanced-topic  ║
║ 26 ║ new-advanced-topic ║ new-advanced-topic2 ║
╚════╩════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

- I want the post's URL to depend only on the post's ID. So if the user requested `www.example.com/post/25/pla-pla-pla`, The post that will be displayed is the one which it's id is 25.
- When a user requests the link `www.example.com/post/{%post_id%}/pla-pla-pla`, I want WordPress to redirect him to `www.example.com/post/{%post_id%}/{%post_title%}`.

So if user requested `www.example.com/post/25/pla-pla-pla`, WordPress will redirect him to `www.example.com/post/25/new-advanced-topic` and display the post with `ID=25`.

And if user requested `www.example.com/post/26/new-advanced-topic2`, WordPress will redirect him to `www.example.com/post/26/new-advanced-topic` and display the post with `ID=26`.

And if user requested `www.example.com/post/100/new-advanced-topic`, a 404 error should appear to him since there's no post stored in the database with `ID=100`.

I tried to write a new rewrite_rule to do this but I couldn't figer any way to write it's regex.

How can I do this using the `wp_rewrite` rules.

Comment: I haven't even thought this through properly but I can promise you that you are up for a world of pain with that as soon as you e.g. use plugins.

Comment: The part of requesting `post/25/anything-here` and serve the post with ID 25 and redirecting to correct URL, is the easy part. Having two same slugs I think is more difficult. Currently [WordPress allows same slugs for diffrent content types](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18962) but not for the same content type. Think about it, it is really a very bad approach. It is bad to have two same titles, even worst if they share the slug. I can not think in any valid use case or any good reason to do it. Why do you want to do such thing?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to do this keeping `post_name` unique. Otherwise, it might cause many troubles. We can use `post_title` with `sanitize_title`. In this way, you can keep your URL nice and clean, and your `post_name` will remain unique as well.

First we will need to write custom permalink structure.

```
function my_awesome_permalink( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    $url= trailingslashit( home_url('/post/'. $post->ID .'/'. sanitize_title($post->post_title) .'/' ) );
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'my_awesome_permalink', 10, 3 );
```

Now, our custom permalink structure is ready. It will become `www.example.com/post/{%post_id%}/{%post_title%}` e.g.: `www.example.com/post/25/my-awesome-post-title` . We will need to add proper rewrite rule to make WP understand and return the right post.

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $new_rules['^post/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?p=$matches[1]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

With above code, you will be able to make your post permalink structure to `www.example.com/post/25/my-awesome-post-title` and it will show correct post.

One problem with above code is, you won't be able to edit post slug from post editor. But your post url now comes from post title, which is editable!

Comment: @birgire thanks for pointing it out. I actually copied it from my functions.php and forgot to remove that part. Edited now.

Comment: It didn't work :( . I added it to the `functions.php` file and it didn't work. I tried also to add `flush_rewrite_rules();` and nothing changed.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf did you put these codes properly? I have tested, and working. However, you will need to resave permalink from Settings > Permalink. It will flush rewrite rules. And you should avoid using `flush_rewrite_rules()`, unless extensively necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand that you want to use **post ID** instead of **Post Title** .

and you have trouble because of the same titles name .

If that's right , the solution will be like following :

1 - change **permalink** to **custom structure** like the following figure

[image]

2- go to **phpmyadmin** and change your **posts name** like following figure

[image]

Comment: if that is not the answer just tell me more

Comment: I want both of the **post ID** and **Post Title** to appear in the URL. But choosing the right post to display should depend only on the **post ID**. The Post's title has no affect in displaying posts. Beside that, I don't want to change the database every time someone adds a new post. I want to do this using `rewrite_mod` so it's applied on all posts.

Comment: there are many problem may appear to you , if you use the same post titles [ SEO ], look to this article  http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-prevent-duplicate-post-titles-in-wordpress/